# Weird Chrome Developer Tools debugger bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, underscore.js, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

Every so often when I'm viewing a page in Chrome with Developer Tools open, and that page includes Underscore, Developer Tools will suddenly jump into debugger mode and pause at the same spot, line 1206 of underscore.js, which is the line starting "render" in this section:

```
try {
  render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
} catch (e) {
  e.source = source;
  throw e;
}
```

I'm not asking the damn thing to debug, and I'm not adding a breakpoint at that spot. I've got this on several otherwise different pages. Has anybody else seen this phenomenon, and is there anything I can do to stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Paused on a JavaScript breakpoint

This means that the script found the following statement:

```
debugger;
```

In this particular case, it looks like `debugger;` is somewhere in the string being passed to `new Function` (you'd need to look at the scope variables and find `source`'s value to check that).

Comment: Thanks Niet - I don't have that line in my own code, and it's not coming up in underscore.js - I'll have to try this the next time this happens and report the results back here.

Comment: OK, it just happened again.. The Scope Variables pane in Dev Tools doesn't expand, so nothing to see there.. I'm unable to get a value for source from the console, out of scope. Am I doing it right? Just checked the underscore minimised file I'm including, and there's definitely no debugger line in that, and none in my project. Weird!